# Python Linear Diffrential equation

Tags: python, differential-equations

So i have 3 equations: 
R=5, V=10, C=10

R*C*dUc(t)/dt + Uc(t) = Vdc

i(t)= C*dUc(t)/dt

Ur(t)= i(t)*R

i solved the diff equation using scypy dsolve to acquire Uc(t) but then how do i use it in the other equations? i tried to take the derivative of the function to use in the 2nd equation but it tells me theres more than one variable.

my code:

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as nm
import pylab as pl
t = nm.arange(0,1,0.002)
r=5
v=10
c=10

#solving diff equation
t=Symbol('t')
u=Function('u')
uu= Derivative(u(t),t)
uc = dsolve(r*c*uu+u(t)-v,u(t))

#finding i
i = c * Derivative(uc)

#finding r
ur = i*r

#plot
t = nm.arange(0,1,0.002)
u = uc
i = c * Derivative(uc)
ur = i*r

pl.subplot(3,1,1)
pl.plot(t,u, '-r')
pl.grid()
pl.ylabel('capacitator voltage')

pl.subplot(3,1,2)
pl.plot(t,i, '-b')
pl.grid()
pl.ylabel('current')

pl.subplot(3,1,3)
pl.plot(t,r, '-')
pl.grid()
pl.ylabel('resistor')

pl.show
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes derivative takes two mandatory arguments : the function and the point at which you want the derivative.

So I assume you want

```
i = c * Derivative(uc, t)
```